# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: app at <App> Laravel 8 & Vue 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

I have the following problem which repeats a lot to me when using Vue 3 and Laravel somewhere. I'm just getting started and have a virtually clean app and can still see this issue exist. Namely, Vuejs 3 from Laravel 8 do not work for me.
I get an error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: app
> at  app.js:13797

***app.js***

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue';

import App from './App.vue';
const app = createApp({App});
app.mount("#app");
```

***App.vue***

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup: () => ({
    greeting: 'Hello World from Vue 3!'
  })
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

***webpack.mix.js***

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {}, [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')])
    .version();
```

***welcome.blade.php***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<app>

</app>
</div>
<script src="{{ url('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `createApp(App)`, not `{App}`, which is a shorthand for `{App: App}`.